# Bandit Issue with Pyproject.toml

Tags: python, bandit-python

I'm trying to use `pyproject.toml` to exclude the `venv/` directory. But it is not recognising the option.

```
[tool.bandit]
exclude = "/venv"

[tool.black]
exclude = "(venv)"

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
skip = "venv"
balanced_wrapping = true
atomic = true
```

If I use the CLI option like so:

```
$ bandit -v -r . --exclude "/venv"
```

the directory is excluded. But if I just run bandit, it doesn't exclude the directory even though I have it in the `pyproject.toml`.

My bandit version is: 1.7.1.

Answer (score 10):

`exclude` did not work for me, so I looked through [official docs](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit) and found this:

[image]

We can specify dirs (and files as well) that we want to exclude in a list format

**pyproject.toml:**

```
[tool.bandit]
exclude_dirs = ["venv",]
```

From [this](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) documentation:

"Also you can configure bandit via pyproject.toml file. In this case you would explicitly specify the path to configuration via -c too."

Therefore, CLI option would look like this:

```
bandit -v -r . -c "pyproject.toml"
```

*(will work without quotes as well)*

---

[image]

---

*I've never used bandit before, so if I got your question wrong - please feel free to write back, we will figure that out :D*

Comment: There's one other detail left as a trap for the unwary: if you're using Python prior to 3.11, you need to install the `toml` module or use `bandit[toml]` to pull in the optional dependency.

https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/318 touches on the need for an explicit `-c` argument.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude directory `venv`, this command works fine for me :

```bash
bandit -r . -x */venv/*
```